# merging/joining list of tuples in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, merge, tuples

I have 2 list of tuples

```
a = [(123, 0, 1), (245, 0, 1)]
b = [(123, 1, 0), (678, 1, 0)]
```

I want to merge these 2 lists in such a way that my output is :

```
merged_list = [(123, 1, 1), (245, 0, 1), (678, 1,0)]
```

I found this piece of code

```
def inner_join(a, b):
L = a + b
L.sort(key=itemgetter(0)) # sort by the first column
for _, group in groupby(L, itemgetter(0)):
    row_a, row_b = next(group), next(group, None)
    if row_b is not None: # join
        yield row_a + row_b[1:]
```

when I execute this, it returns me the tuple whose first element is common

```
result = list(inner_join(a,b))
result - [(123,1,1)]
```

How can I resolve this, so that I am able to get required solution

```
[(123, 1, 1), (245, 0, 1), (678, 1,0)]
```

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: There are no standard tools for this. What have you written so far?

Comment: What are the rules for merging the first tuple? We can guess from the example, but you should state them explicitly. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I have edited the question, I am not able to find from where I got this solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group similar elements, based on the first value of the tuple.

```
a = [(123, 0, 1), (245, 0, 1)]
b = [(123, 1, 0), (678, 1, 0)] 

from itertools import groupby
grouped_list = [(k,list(g)) for k,g in groupby(sorted([*a,*b]),key= lambda x: x[0])]
```

This will give you output like:

```
[(123, [(123, 0, 1), (123, 1, 0)]), (245, [(245, 0, 1)]), (678, [(678, 1, 0)])]
```

Next we need to sum the second and third value of tuple inside grouped list to get the required output.

```
out = [(k,*[sum(x) for x in zip(*x)][1:]) for k,x in grouped_list]
```

Which will give you your required output

```
[(123, 1, 1), (245, 0, 1), (678, 1, 0)]
```

If you prefer one-liners:

```
[(k,*[sum(x) for x in zip(*list(g))][1:]) for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted([*a,*b]),key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use the first value of each tuple as a key in which case changing tuple a to a dictionary might be more practical. I'm sure there's a better way but you could try this. Instead of

```
a = [(123, 0, 1), (245, 0, 1)]
```

try

```
a_dic = {123: (0,1), 245: (0,1)}
```

You can then check b (the list of tuples) against the keys in the dictionary. If no matches are found the new key and values are added to the dictionary. If a key matches then its values are added.

```
for x in b:
    temp_tuple = x[1], x[2]
    if not x[0] in a_dic.keys():
         a_dic.update({x[0]: temp_tuple})
    else:
         new_value = tuple(map(sum,zip(temp_tuple, a_dic.get(x[0]))))
         a_dic.update({x[0]:new_value})

print(a_dic)
```

Result is:

```
{123: (1, 1), 245: (0, 1), 678: (1, 0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. It is working. You can change/tweak the code as you want. Hope the code is simple enough to understand.

```
a = [(123, 0, 1), (245, 0, 1)]
b = [(123, 1, 0), (678, 1, 0)]
# print (a)
# print (b)
c1=[]
c=[]
for element1 in b:
    c1.append(element1)
    for element2 in a:
        if element1[0]==element2[0]:
            x=(element1[0],element1[1]+element2[1],element1[2]+element2[2])
            c.append(x)

for element2 in a:
    c1.append(element2)
for element in c1:
    flag=0
    for element1 in c:
        if element1[0]==element[0]:
            flag=1
    if (flag==0):
        c.append(element)
print(c)
```